# Нужно ли тире?

Tags: пунктуация

Из комментария в блоге: "Ну так, рука мастера (—) есть рука мастера!" Нужно тут тире или нет?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Нет, тире здесь не нужно, так как составное именное сказуемое употреблено со связкой "есть", то есть сказуемое полное. Обычно эта связка в предложениях подобного типа опускается, вместо неё и ставится тире. Но здесь особый случай: без этой связки предложение выглядело бы странным. Ср.: Рука мастера - рука мастера. И вообще, в выражениях вроде "школа есть школа", "дети есть дети" и т.п. знаки не нужны.

Answer (score 0):

«Книги суть реки, напояющие вселенную мудростью". Здесь отсутствие тире по той же причине.